# I have a list of words. I want to add a counter variable associated with each word. How do I do this?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list of words, let's say it's

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I have a document where I've already pre-processed a text file into a matrix, and it goes like this:

```
a,b,c,d
0,1,1,0
1,1,0,0
1,1,1,1
```

Where 1 is the presence of the word in a sentence, and 0 is the absence of that word in a sentence.  I would like to go through that matrix, line by line, and increment some sort of counter associated with the original word list up above, so I can know how many of each word was found in the sentences at the end.

How can I make this?  Do I have to create an associative array, or a 2d array?  Is there a way to create a new variable within the array associated with each word that I can increment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is `sum` each column since it's just 0s and 1s!

```
import numpy as np
array = numpy.array((matrix))
answer = np.apply_along_axis(sum,0,array[1::])
my_dict = dict(zip(matrix[0],answer))
```

now you have a dictionary where the keys are the words and the values is the total number of appearances!

Comment: of course! Numpy is great and if you're dealing with a matrix, it is the module to go with! Glad I could help

Comment: I find it a little surprising that this works.  This makes it seem like `matrix[0]` has the keys, in which case your `answer =` line should fail.  Did you actually try this?

Comment: very good point! I made the edit so the first row is not counted in the summing. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use [*collections.Counter*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to tally the word counts:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> filedata = '''\
0,1,1,0
1,1,0,0
1,1,1,1
'''
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> for line in filedata.splitlines():
    a, b, c, d = map(int, line.split(','))
    counter['a'] += a
    counter['b'] += b
    counter['c'] += c
    counter['d'] += d


>>> counter
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer not to hardcode the keys, so maybe something like:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open("abcd.txt", "rb") as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    c = Counter()
    for row in reader:
        c.update({k: int(v) for k,v in row.iteritems()})
```

which produces

```
>>> c
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open("abc") as f:
    next(f)                 # skip header
    dic = defaultdict(int) 
    for line in f:
        for x,y in zip("abcd",map(int,line.split(","))):
            dic[x] += y
    print dic
```

**output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 3, 'd': 1})
```

using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
with open("abc") as f:
    next(f)
    c = Counter()
    for line in f:
        c.update( dict(zip ("abcd", map(int,line.split(",")) )) )
    print c
```

**output:**

```
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the matrix described, you can do this:

```
mat=[['a','b','c','d'],
     [ 0,  1,  1,  0],
     [ 1,  1,  0,  0],
     [ 1,  1,  1,  1]]

print {t[0]:sum(t[1:]) for t in zip(*mat)}
```

prints:

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 3, 'd': 1}
```

Comment: Nice. Note that on Python prior to 2.7 / 3.1 you need to do `dict([(t[0],sum(t[1:])) for t in zip(*mat)])` since there is no dict comprehension.